# Global variables accessible to other websites opened in same tab

Tags: web-browser, javascript, chrome, data-leakage, firefox

Today I found a security issue with Chrome (or maybe other browsers I haven't tested yet).
What happens is that once you open a site and then open another site in the same tab, the previous site's global variables are accessible to the current site in that tab. I have demonstrated it in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDFKsLaecOs

So is this happening just with my Chrome (which is updated to latest version) or anyone else faced this?

**This is how you can reproduce it:**

I logged in to exotel.com site and they are using a `name` variable to store currently logged in user's name. You can use it in console and check its value.

Now go to any other site in same tab and try accessing that variable from exotel. Your name will be displayed or just add a button from HTML in inspector and on click of that display the name variable.

Comment: What is the vulnerability you think you have found? Why do you think the current site has access to that data, rather than your browser having access to it as you'd expect. I would test it if I were you - I do not think you have found a security issue at all.

Comment: `name` is not a global variable. It's a property of the `window` object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name

Comment: This looks like a bug, but not necessarily a big one. In the past `window.name` was used to pass messages back and forth but I doubt anybody does that anymore. According to the WHATWG HTML Living Standard, `window.name` should be set to an empty string after navigating to a different domain. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#dom-name